# why sending image in python using form with post is not working

Tags: python, forms, post, flask, python-requests

Trying to send an image using **Requests** package to **Flask** server using `forms` with `post`. But the flask server is not able to parse the key `image`. How to send the image in proper format with requests using forms.

**Flask server.py**

```
@app.route('/api/<model_name>/predict/', methods=['POST'])
def predict(model_name):

    if "image" in request.files.keys():
        return jsonify({"msg": "key found"})

    print("image", request.files)
    return str(), 200
```

**Requests client.py**

```
def get_predictions(path):

   url = "http://localhost:9020/api/fasterrcnn/predict/"

   payload = {"image": (path.name, open(path, "rb"), "image/jpeg")}
   headers = {'content-type': "multipart/form-data"}
   response = requests.post(
       url, data=payload, headers=headers, stream=True)

   pprint(response.text)
```

Could someone please tell me the possible cause and solution? If I've missed out anything, over- or under-emphasized a specific point, let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` [documentation page](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) states that you should use `files=` parameter for posting multipart files.

Example:

```py
import requests

def get_predictions(path):
   url = "http://localhost:9020/api/fasterrcnn/predict/"

   files = {"image": (path.name, open(path, "rb"), "image/jpeg")}
   response = requests.post(url, files=files)

   pprint(response.text)
```